# How to perform a XPATH Conditional SUM

Tags: xml, xpath-2.0, xquery-3.0, xpath-3.0

I'm trying to build an xpath sum expression with a filter that will some the seconds for filtered time frame and unit.  I think this fairly simple but just can't seem to get my hands around it.

Assuming I have a XML document like:

```
<root>
    <hourly>
        <hour>
            <unit>1</unit>
            <timestamp>2015-05-02 00:00:00-0500</timestamp>
            <operationaltime>3600</operationaltime>
        </hour>
        <hour>
            <unit>1</unit>
            <timestamp>2015-05-02 01:00:00-0500</timestamp>
            <operationaltime>3113</operationaltime>
        </hour>
        <hour>
            <unit>2</unit>
            <timestamp>2015-05-02 00:00:00-0500</timestamp>
            <operationaltime>1809</operationaltime>
        </hour>
        <hour>
            <unit>2</unit>
            <timestamp>2015-05-02 01:00:00-0500</timestamp>
            <operationaltime>3444</operationaltime>
        </hour>
    </hourly>
</root>
```

Here is what I have:

```
sum(hourly/hour[/unit=2 and /timestamp='2015-05-02 01:00:00-0500']/operationaltime)
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use absolute paths when you want them to be relative. That is, when you say `/unit=2`, that goes back to the root of the context item; if you want it to be relative to the hour, use either `./unit=2` or just `unit=2`. Thus:

```
declare context item := <root>
    <hourly>
        <hour>
            <unit>1</unit>
            <timestamp>2015-05-02 00:00:00-0500</timestamp>
            <operationaltime>3600</operationaltime>
        </hour>
        <hour>
            <unit>1</unit>
            <timestamp>2015-05-02 01:00:00-0500</timestamp>
            <operationaltime>3113</operationaltime>
        </hour>
        <hour>
            <unit>2</unit>
            <timestamp>2015-05-02 00:00:00-0500</timestamp>
            <operationaltime>1809</operationaltime>
        </hour>
        <hour>
            <unit>2</unit>
            <timestamp>2015-05-02 01:00:00-0500</timestamp>
            <operationaltime>3444</operationaltime>
        </hour>
    </hourly>
</root>;

sum(hourly/hour[unit=2 and timestamp='2015-05-02 01:00:00-0500']/operationaltime)
```

...yields a result of `3444`, which looks about right to me.